Convert time results
I have this result from my query 06:30 and 00:00 in which I would like to have empty space only when a 00:00 time is displaying.
This is my query
SUBSTRING(RIGHT('0000' + CAST(RST.DEPOT_DEPARTURE_TIME AS VARCHAR(4)), 4), 1, 2) + 
':' + 
SUBSTRING(RIGHT('0000' + CAST(RST.DEPOT_DEPARTURE_TIME AS VARCHAR(4)), 4), 3, 2) AS [Route_Start_Time]

I expect and empty space every time the record shows 00:00

Please update your question to show sample data and the result you want to achieve based on that data. Please also include a complete, valid, SQL statement showing what you’ve managed to achieve so far. All as editable text, appropriately formatted (data as tables, code as code, etc)

Sounds like you might want ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(5), RST. NULLIF(DEPOT_DEPARTURE_TIME, '00:00:00'), 24), '') but really unclear.

Which dbms are you using? (Both the code snippet above, and comments, contain product specific functions.)

Thanks NickW and Charlieface for your comments, should I place this query after my query, I tried but it's giving and error:       SUBSTRING(RIGHT('0000' + CAST(RST.DEPOT_DEPARTURE_TIME AS VARCHAR(4)), 4), 1, 2) + ':' +
SUBSTRING(RIGHT('0000' + CAST(RST.DEPOT_DEPARTURE_TIME AS VARCHAR(4)), 4), 3, 2) AS [Route_Start_Time],
ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(5), [RST.DEPOT_DEPARTURE_TIME], NULLIF([RST.DEPOT_DEPARTURE_TIME], '00:00:00'), 24), '')  Incorrect syntax near ','.

sql microsft 2019

Please don’t add informing comments. Update your question and/or tag it so that your question reflects what you are currently asking
